# VBA deletes image in body instead of header in MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have MS Word files that have a header with 2 Text Boxes and one image (as logo) and some tables, texts and images in body.
I'm trying to remove the image in header (logo) with this VBA code:

```
Dim tmp As Shape
Dim dShape As Shape

For Each tmp In ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes
    If tmp.Type = msoPicture Then
        Set dShape = tmp
    End If
Next
dShape.Delete
```

In the first test it worked correctly!  After that it removes body image instead of header image!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we should first select the `Shape` we want to delete!!
I don't know why when I say `shape1.Delete` it thinks : let me see, mmmm... I think i is better to do `shape2.Delete` , so i'll do that.
any way this works:

```
dShape.Select
dShape.Delete
```

VBA is a fool (Just like its platform)!